# How to copy plain text from web pages in Safari?

Tags: safari, copy-paste, formatting

When using Safari, I find no plug-in to force copied text from web pages to not include rich-text formatting and only copy the raw ascii characters.

How can I, using Safari, only copy plain text into the clipboard from web pages?

If that is not possible, is there a way in Microsoft Word for Mac 2011 to only paste plain text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst copying from Safari as plain text is not possible as far as I know, the OS X system shortcut for **pasting as plain text is ⇧⌥⌘V**.

For Microsoft Word, go to Edit → Paste Special → Unformatted Text or Edit → Paste and Match Formatting.

Comment: @WilliamKF I don't have a copy of Word on Mac so I don't know for sure, but Word on Windows has an option to Keep Text Only or Match Destination Styles. Maybe it's doing the latter and the insertion point is set to bold?

Comment: The `Command Option Shift V` (⇧⌥⌘V) is partially plain, it drops the font name and size to match the pasting context, but any **bolded text** is pasted as **bold**.

Answer (score 0):

Drag text into a plain text application such as Text Wrangler (free), BBEdit etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have formatted text in your clipboard, and you want its unformatted version in your clipboard, you can run this command from Terminal.app:

```
pbpaste | pbcopy
```